# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to Update existing record and Insert new ones in Bulk third party API data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, hangfire

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have a third party API to consume and then save THE bulk record into the DB using a background schedule with HangFire.

api:

```
https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/UserAccount/api/AccountDetail
```

In appsettings.json I have:

```
  "Endpoints": {
    "accountBalanceUrl": "https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/UserAccount/api/AccountDetail"
  }
```

Then JSON Result is shown below:

```
{
  "AccountNumber": "string",
  "AccountName": "string",
  "CurrentBalance": 0,
  "AvailableBalance": 0,
  "Currency": "string"
}
```

So far, I have done this:

BalanceEnquiryResponseDto:

```
public class BalanceEnquiryResponseDto
{
    public List<BalanceListDto> AccountBalances
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

BalanceListDto:

```
public class BalanceListDto
{
    public string AccountNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string AccountName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal CurrentBalance
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal AvailableBalance
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Currency
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

BaseResponse:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IAccountBalanceService
{
    Task<BaseResponse> CreateAccountBalanceAsync();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class AccountBalanceService : IAccountBalanceService
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly HttpClient _myClient;
    public AccountBalanceService(
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        ILogger logger,
        IMapper mapper,
        HttpClient myClient,
        IConfiguration config
        )
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _logger = logger;
        _myClient = myClient;
        _config = config;
    }
    public async Task<BaseResponse> CreateAccountBalanceAsync()
    {
        var balanceResponse = new BaseResponse();
        try
        {
            string accountBalanceUrl = _config.GetSection("Endpoints").GetValue<string>("accountBalanceUrl");

            HttpResponseMessage response = _myClient.GetAsync(bankBranchUrl).Result;

            var stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            BankBranchResponse list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BalanceEnquiryResponseDto>(stringResult);
            foreach (var singleBalance in list.AccountBalances)
            {
                CustomerBalance res = new CustomerBalance();

                //set all fields here
                res.AccountNumber = singleBalance.AccountNumber;
                res.AccountName = singleBalance.AccountName;
                res.CurrentBalance = singleBalance.CurrentBalance;
                res.AvailableBalance = singleBalance.AvailableBalance;
                res.Currency = singleBalance.Currency;
                await _unitOfWork.CustomerBalances.InsertAsync(res);
            }
            await _unitOfWork.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("An Error occured " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return balanceResponse;
    }
}
```

The records coming from the third party api should be save into CustomerBalance table using HangFire.

AccountNumber is unique.

Now want I want to achieve is this, in the foreach loop, if AccountNumber exists it should update every other field. But if AccountNumber does not exist, it should insert a new record.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, you should write the logic by yourself. According to your description, you need firstly send request to the api to get the result and then update or insert record according to this result. It's better you could write a condition inside the foreach to decide if it need insert or delete.